# User Revoke Permission

Tags: android, permissions

When a user revokes permissions in settings of the phone for the android app, the process will be terminated/killed and when the user opens the app again, it will crash. Is there a possibility that the app will not crash in order for the user to remain in the activity he or she just left ? If there is, how? I am still new to android development.

Comment: _"and when user opens the app again, it will crash"_ Why would it crash? Are you not checking for permission before every operation that requires a permission?

Comment: @Michael, I was checking. I read also here that when user granted the permission and by some time he or she revokes it on the phone settings, the app is running on the background and it will terminate or kill the process after the permissions are revoked.

Comment: Yeah I'm with you so far. What I don't understand is why the app would crash when you try to start it again. It sounds to me like your app is trying to do something that requires a permission without checking whether it has that permission. You need to check for permission _every time_, not just once.

Comment: @Michael I see. I got you. Thank you so much. Appreciate it! :)

Comment: @Michael, even if I added codes in my onResume, all the data will be null causes the app to crash.

Comment: No one here can possibly know what _"all the data will be null causes the app to crash"_ means because we haven't seen any of your code. I also did not suggest checking for permissions in `onResume`; you should check for permission right before you're about to do any operation that requires a permission.

Answer (score 0):

When app is re-opened you can catch `onResume` and check if you still have the permission to continue whatever they were doing before turning the permission off.

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        //We have the location permission!
        //We can continue :)
    }
    else
    {
        //We don't have the permission anymore :(
        finish();
        //Or we can request it again, maybe show a dialog saying that it's needed in order to continue?
    }
}
```

Comment: still it gets error, the data during broadcast/live video will be null.

Comment: If you don't have the permission anymore, you should pause whatever is broadcasting/getting the data until either 1) user gives you the permission again 2) user wants to stop whatever is happening

Comment: Not pause the permission. But if you no longer have the permission you need then you should stop whatever code is being executed that is dependant on the permission.

Comment: Okay sir! Thank you. I understand it now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that requesting permissions in the `onResume()` method is not a good idea, due to the fact that if for instance the user didn't grant the permission a dialog will appear asking the user to grant the permission and the activity will go in to the `onPause()` state. Then if the user will deny the permission, the activity will go back to the `onResume()` state and ask for the permission again, which will cause an infinite loop if the user won't approve or check the "Don't ask me again" checkBox. I suggested you implement the logic in the `onStart()` method.